# Rounding error with pi

Tags: java, android, math, double, pi

I am trying to make a sequence of code that calculates the volume of a cone based on a user input height and radius (see below).

My problem is that the answer comes out wrong (but not by a long way). Using the example of height = 5, radius = 10, I get an answer from the code of 500 (treating pi as exactly 3), but calculating manually I get ~523.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the variable type I am declaring pi under (double then converting to long) but I have struggled to make any other combination of variable types work.

What is the correct version of this below that will store pi properly (to at least 5 or 6 dec places)?

```
                double piDouble = Math.PI;

                long height = Long.parseLong(heightString);
                long pi = (new Double(piDouble)).longValue();
                long radius = Long.parseLong(radiusString);

                long volumeBase = (pi*(radius*radius)*height) / 3;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`long pi = (new Double(piDouble)).longValue();` is a long, so it is equal to `3`, exactly.

If you need more precision, use double all the way, and round at the end only. This should give you the result you expect:

```
double piDouble = Math.PI;
long height = Long.parseLong(heightString);
long radius = Long.parseLong(radiusString);
double volumeBase = (piDouble * (radius * radius) * height) / 3;
```

You can then round the result if you need to:

```
long roundedDownVolume = (long) volumeBase; //round down
long roundedVolume = Math.round(volumeBase); //or round to the closest long
```

Comment: After this I want to be able to convert to different metrics (i.e. mm, cm etc.), via "volume = volumeBase / 1000;" but cannot do this with a double. Is there a way to maintain the details of the double but still being able to perform the division?

Comment: @DonRoby not sure what difference you make between truncate and round down ;-)

Comment: @Kurt What do you mean *"can't do this with a double"*? Unless you need to round the results, you should only use doubles and show the results to the user with the right amount of precision / decimals.

Comment: As the value is approximately 523.5987755982989, the correct rounding would be up to 524.

Comment: @DonRoby Ok I understand what you mean - I was sticking to the op's question where he said he expected 523.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise I was declaring the result as a long elsewhere in the code, and it was unable to convert from long to double.

This works well, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BigDecimal for this kind of arithmetic.

Comment: Since the OP only requires 5 to 6 decimal places, doubles should be precise enough (unless the cone height goes to the moon and is in nanometers)...

Comment: I still think using BigDecimal makes life easier.